# Serialization of draft entities throws entity not found

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I have a problem I struggle with and it's related to SQLFilter I have to filter out draft entities when the user has no permission to view them.

Basically, this happens somehow on nested relationships when symfony/api-platform serializer tries to serialize deeply.

Example:

```
User {
  id: 2,
  name: "John doe",
  profile: { car: 1},
  owner: {
     id: 1,
     name: "Doe john",
     profile: { car: 1},
  }
}
```

When the car is 'draft' and I serialize user(2) without an owner (remove him from context), the car is null, with no errors and this is the expected behavior. However, when I add to serialize owner as well, this is thrown https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/62ed63bbbe3f59dcacb7dadb574895f5cb27a257/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php#L229 for User(2).owner.profile.car

If I modify the ProxyFactory code then it works just fine as expected, even for regular not found errors. I wonder if that throw is really required.

Not sure if this is a doctrine issue or serialization issue, if serialization then if it's on api-platform side or symfony side.

Thank you for any useful insights.